# Incorrect data in Constructor

Tags: c#, error-handling, constructor

I have a class

```
class Rational
{
   private int _n;
   private int _m;

   public Rational(int n, int m)
   {
      _n = n;
      _m = m;
   }
}
```

But `m` should be `> 0`. What should I do to notify user that he enter incorrect data to constructor?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could throw an `ArgumentException` or add a contract requiring `m > 0`

```
if(m <= 0) throw new ArgumentException("Denominator must be positive");
```

or

```
public Rational(int n, int m)
{
    Contract.Requires(m > 0);
    _n = n;
    _m = m;
}
```

Comment: @Sergey Gavruk Throwing an `ArgumentException` or `ArgumentNullException` in a constructor is perfectly normal, and a practice used in many of the core .net classes.

Comment: @Sergey - There's no reason not to that I'm aware of, as long as no resources (e.g. file handles) are leaked. It's common for BCL classes to do this - if an object cannot be created in a valid state then the only sensible thing it can do is throw an exception.

Answer (score 3):

Although it's controversial (especially in C++), I think the most straightforward thing to do here would be throwing an `ArgumentException`.

Microsoft guidelines [recommend throwing exceptions from constructors](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229060.aspx) when it makes sense, for example if the arguments do not allow creation of a usable object (which is your case).

Answer (score 2):

Within C# there are official constructor design guidelines in the article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229060.aspx and in there it says **Do throw exceptions from instance constructors if appropriate**.

I would say to throw an argument exception as other people have said but I would use a few caveats that if you have created anything that is Disposable within your object, clean up before throwing the exception